# Can't get magnific popup to work, two javascript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, magnific-popup

I am trying to make a lightbox gallery and have used the example source code.

Here is the documentation I read over: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**I am not sure what the errors mean or what to do with them.**

In a video tutorial I watched, they said something about a jquery conflict being a potential problem. On a different page of the website, I used a Kwicks sliding menu (which also used jquery). That's the only thing I can think of.

I would really appreciate any help you would be able to give me!

**Thank you!  There are no more errors, but now I need to make the hovering on the image work with the zooming in magnifying cursor.**

**I have made the hovering work, now I need to make the zooming in magnifying cursor work. I have attached a page of what I what the cursor to be when it hovers.**

Example: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

**I have figured out the zoom cursor! Thanks for all the help!**

Comment: You need to include [jquery reference](http://jquery.com/download/) and unless you include this, the other plugin won't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation of the plugin **[Magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)**  you are using suggests -

*Including files*

```
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

**Remember**  : You need to include jQuery file reference, for the plugin to work; rather every jQuery plugin. And in the specified order. This is the sole reason behind `$ not defined` and `undefined in not a function`.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the fast reply. There are no more errors, but now I need to make the hovering on the image work with the zooming in magnifying pointer.