# jquery magnificPopup Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have found [this](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/demo/ubeasa/) template and I want to use in my angular 1 application. I have include all directories to my project correctly. When I try to start my application, I have this error:
[image]
I have tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444807/cant-get-magnific-popup-to-work-two-javascript-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24444855/6608257) but it did not work.

Can you please help to to solve this issue ?

**Update**
This is my headers:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900italic,900&subset=latin,greek,greek-ext,vietnamese,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/img/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/img/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="assets/img/favicon-96x96.png">
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


..................................
..................................

..................................


..................................

..................................
..................................
..................................


    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
  
  
  <!-- here this load js files -->
   <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery Easing -->
 <script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Waypoints -->
 <script src="../js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Carousel -->
 <script src="../js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <!-- countTo -->
 <script src="../js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
 <!-- Flexslider -->
 <script src="../js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
 <!-- Magnific Popup -->
 <script src="../js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
 <!-- Main -->
 <script src="../js/main.js"></script>


    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

when I click on error I get this:
[image]

Comment: can you show us the header of your page showing what your are loading and how you are calling the functions.

Comment: @AndyDonegan I have update to add files I am loading

Comment: Why is this question tagged under [angularjs]?

Comment: Could be many things currently, can you set up a basic page just load the minimum and create a small popup to prove you are loading the js file for the popup to commence with ? Try loading the MagnifiPop Js file before the closing </Body> as an initial test.